# Observer pattern reload multiple pages PHP

Tags: php, oop, web

I have implemented an observer pattern within my code that observes a certain state. If this state is changed, `processReceivedData()` is supposed to refresh multiple pages at the same time if they are opened in the browser (or in general, update multiple pages where the observed state is used).

```
public function processReceivedData() {
        //header("location: ".$_SERVER['PHP_SELF']);
        header("Refresh: 0; url=".$_SERVER['PHP_SELF']);
    }
```

It will only reload the current page I am on and I understand why (How would the other browser window know there has been a change when the algorithm is already done and `PHP` is not dynamic?)

How can I reload the other pages, too and on change? They all use the same observer and observed and on change this function is called

```
public function setState($newState, $_PizzaID) {
        if($this->db->query("UPDATE bestelltepizza SET status='$newState' WHERE PizzaID = '$_PizzaID'")) {
            parent::notify();
        } else {
            $this->state = "Unable to connect to database via setState(); method";
        }
    }
```

I can't think of a proper way to solve this as I don't know all possibilities of `PHP` and if this is possible with only `PHP` or if it would only work with `javascript` or else.

*If I failed clearing out my exact problem or if any questions pop up to my question, please comment and I will clarify. Help very much appreciated, thanks.*